# Imagemagick: distorting images on top of background?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, distortion

I've got one background image: [sky.jpg](https://s12.postimg.org/y4q1hw5al/sky.jpg)

And two transparent PNG images: [gradient.png](https://s22.postimg.org/ja721f7a9/gradient.png) and [tree.png](https://s15.postimg.org/os8m71tbf/tree.png)

Now I want to draw the two images on the background with a perspective distortion, like this:

[image: combined.jpg]
The destination coordinates of the two images are, in clockwise order (starting top left) :

gradient: `62,129` `421,218` `383,458` `147,548`

tree: `445,100` `765,47` `698,368` `529,396`

I cannot figure out how to start with one image (in this case the sky background) and then take another image and draw that with perspective distortion **to specific destination coords** within the background. Also doing this with more than one image at a time, within one convert command, troubles me.

For example, when I start with just one image (the gradient) and try this:

```
convert sky.jpg \( gradient.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent \
 +distort Perspective "0,0 62,129 255,0 421,218 255,255 383,458 0,255 147,548" \) \
 -compose src-over -composite result.jpg
```

It gets correctly warped (so the coordinates are *relatively* correct) but it's drawn in the top left corner, not at the coordinates I specify.

Also I'm a bit unsure if my usage of `-compose` and `-composite` is correct (I took this from various IM manual examples).

One other thing that is unclear to me: in case of the 256x256 image, should I use `255,0` and `255,255` and `0,255` as the corner coordinates, or `256,0` and `256,256` and `0,256` ?

Any IM experts who can shed light on these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `-geometry` just before the `-composite` like this:

```
convert -size 800x600 xc:black \( -size 300x200 xc:red \) -geometry +90+10 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Well the point is, in real life situations where I'm doing this, the coordinates are not known. So that would mean I have to add a shell script where I calculate the minimum x and y of the four destination coords, and add a geometry param for that? That's possible but I've got a feeling I'm overcomplicating things...?

Comment: I am not sure I understand... why not `convert sky.jpg \( gradient.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent  +distort Perspective "0,0 62,129 255,0 421,218 255,255 383,458 0,255 147,548" \) -geometry +62+129 -composite result.png`

Comment: In this example, you can immediately see that 62,129 is what I need to specify at geometry. But I need to apply this in situations where the four distort coordinates are *variables*, like `$x1,$y1` till `$x4,$y4`. So I don't know the specific numbers in advance, and thus I don't know which are the top/leftmost coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't know off the top of my head, but will have a think. I guess Eric will tell you before me - he loves distorting stuff ;-)  @emcconville